# Loosen literal type to its corresponding type

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to loosen some literal type in typescript, for example.

```
type T1 = "";
type T2 = 1
```

I would like to get `string` for `T1` and `number` for `T2`.

For collections, I'm not sure, I guess it would be applying it to the generic, but not too concerned about that for now.

In terms of context I'm getting the type from a generic function with const annotation.

```
const f = <const T>(x:T)=> ...
```

because I do need the exact literal type but I also need the looser type (it's supertype?)

For now all I can think about is some type that manually checks whether the type extends it and returns that type.

```
type Z<T>=T extends string ? string : T extends number ? number ...
```

which is fine eventually if no other way is possible.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N9Qo8N) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you, that's similar to what I put in the question. I can do something like that, I was looking for a more direct way maybe leveraging some aspect of typescript I was not so familiar with. You can write up an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no other way to get the primitive type for a given type.

The more complete version of your attempt is described in [type-samurai](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai) package as the [ToPrimitive](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai/blob/main/src/to-primitive.d.ts?plain=1#L13) type:

```
type ToPrimitive<T> = T extends string
  ? string
  : T extends number
  ? number
  : T extends null
  ? null
  : T extends undefined
  ? undefined
  : T extends boolean
  ? boolean
  : T extends bigint
  ? bigint
  : T extends symbol
  ? symbol
  : {
      [K in keyof T]: ToPrimitive<T[K]>;
    };
```

Along with the primitive types such as numbers, strings, and .etc, it also supports nested objects/arrays making the primitive properties to their superset.

Testing:

```
// number
type Case1 = ToPrimitive<1>
// string
type Case2 = ToPrimitive<'str'>
// {a: string}
type Case3 = ToPrimitive<{a: '1'}>
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgFQgBSqYNgDcCmcAvnAGZQQhwDkMAnmPgLQDOAhiAK5RvDUBQ-APRC49RinSYQ2PPgA8yAHxwAvCjj4AHjHwA7ACYs4LGJj0BzYaLhwA-CbPBL123ABcG7bsPG9nEAAjfChXWwd-IJCwjy8dfSM4fwAbZJiIzlSYz2RNeN84TkN8Umd8A3TC4tK9cuy4n0TAiAhk-DY9SubW9s6RNxy8xuNA4AtnGC6xifrc7wTjFjog1sqllbT+208EGLc4AG0AaThnOABrfDoIUhQAXRypLBwCRWO7pQBuPeJvwX7IsFQuJCABhNgsfAARjUkgwzzk8ihSlcpnMVhBcHBkIATLDUPCZC8FNQ0dQUf0EGxPGjnBYiPxMdj8ABmfFPImIqmeahQ6hEJRAA)